# R : Load only once a .RData in a deployed ShinyApp

Tags: r, shiny, loading, rdata

I need to deploy a ShinyApp with [Shiny Server](https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/shiny-server/). To run, my app need data from a `.RData` file (~300 Mo). This `.RData` file is loaded with a `load(...)` statement located in a `global.R` file.
Function of the computer, the loading may need several minutes what is unfriendly for the user.

How can we do in order to make the `.RDate` file load only once so that each new user does not need to re-load the `.RData` file ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you load the object in `global.R`, then just once it should be loaded. Every user after the first should have a fast access to your application.

If you are developing locally your app, you can test what I'm saying in the following way. Start your application with, for instance,

```
 runApp(port=5050)
```

just to set the port. You need some time for your browser to display the app. After loading, take note of the address of your app (should be `127.0.0.1:5050`), close the browser tab of the app (but don't stop R!), open a new tab and put the above address in the address bar. Now, access to your app should be very fast.

This just to say that as long as shiny is up and running, the commands in `global.R` are executed at the beginning and their evaluation is put in the R global environment. They are not executed any time a user connects to the app.

Consider also that you can speed up the loading of an `Rdata` if you save it with the `compress=FALSE` argument. In this way, your file will be bigger, but loading it will be faster.

Comment: Great help!I tried the experience based on `runApp(port=5050)` and it worked very well! It may be obvious but `session$onSessionEnded(function() {stopApp()})` musn't be in the `server.R` so that it works.... Thank you also for `compress = FALSE` : very useful.