# How to load Rdata file only once in ShinyApp

Tags: r, shiny, rdata

I have deployed a shinyapp which uses a .Rdata file of ~700Mb.

The Rdata file is loaded in `server-inputdata.R` file and the `server.R` file looks like as shown below:

```
options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 100*1024^2)

source("helpers.R")
print(sessionInfo())

shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
  source("server-inputdata.R",local = TRUE)
  source("server2.R",local = TRUE)
  source("server3.R",local = TRUE) 
})
```

Here, `server2.R` and `server3.R` has visualization code which uses the data loaded from .Rdata file in `server-inputdata.R`

Whenever the app is loaded, the Rdata file is getting loaded for each user. Could someone help how to load the data only once and provide immediate access to the users.  Checked a similar thread here `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31557428/r-load-only-once-a-rdata-in-a-deployed-shinyapp` which did not help to solve my issue.

Here is the code in `server-inputdata.R`

```
inputDataReactive <- reactive({
    load('04.Rdata')
    return(list("data"=data_results,
                "data_results_table"=data_results_table))
    print("uploaded data")
})
```

Comment: If your deployment is containerised, eg on shinyapps.io, then this simply isn't possible: each user has their own instance of the app.  If this is possible in other configurations, and if so, how to do it, I do not know.  I suspect the solution will be installation-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your source line : `source("server-inputdata.R",local = TRUE)` outside of your server function, as in :

```
options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 100*1024^2)

source("helpers.R")
source("server-inputdata.R",local = TRUE)  # loaded once per session
print(sessionInfo())

shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
  source("server2.R",local = TRUE)
  source("server3.R",local = TRUE) 
})
```

Comment: Tried this approach and did not work. launched the app `runApp(port=5050)` and tried to launch in a webbrowser and the dataset is loading again. To give more info, the `load()` is inside a reactive function as updated in the OP.

Comment: also tried `source("server-inputdata.R",local = FALSE)` as per https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html which should be loaded in global environment, did not help either. The dataset is loaded everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the reactive function did the trick.

```
options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 100*1024^2)
source("helpers.R")
load('04.Rdata')
data<-list("data"=data_results,"data_results_table"=data_results_table)
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
source("server2.R",local = TRUE)
source("server3.R",local = TRUE) 
})
```

And loading the data o